# Trouble installing capybara-webkit on yosemite

Tags: ruby, gcc, rvm, capybara-webkit

I'm on ruby 2.1.1. and I'm getting this error when trying to install capybara-webkit

```
command : gem install capybara-webkit -v1.3.1


gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Xarch_x86_64'
```

gcc version is

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 4.9.2' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Homebrew gcc 4.9.2)
```

Any idea of what is wrong with my setup?  Before Yosemite or the reinstall of rvm everything was fine.

Thank you

Comment: I vaguely recall that this option is specific to the gcc apple provides

Comment: I figured out.  I removed gcc that I installed with brew et relink to the apple gcc and it worked.